# Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io [Connection timed out #110] with right env

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I am using mail trap to test my emails and I am getting the error stated in above in the title.

This is the env files that I have

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=XXXXXddda513d4
MAIL_PASSWORD=da084XXXXXXbbe
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I can not find much on this. What I found was to clear your cache and I did it wand saw no change.

Answer (score 24):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*******
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=from@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=Example
```

switch the MAIL_PORT between (25 or 465 or 587 or 2525)

Answer (score 5):

use port 25 and mail encryption is empty like

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=XXXXXddda513d4
MAIL_PASSWORD=da084XXXXXXbbe
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=
```

Comment: drop the serve and run this artisan command php artisan config:clear again start the serve

Answer (score 0):

The following settings could do the trick:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx
MAIL_PASSWORD=yyy
```

Remove the `MAIL_ENCRYPTION` line entirely. It's also worth checking that the ports are open on your firewall (if you have one), or check that you are able to connect to port `465`.

Answer (score 0):

could you please try this code ?

```
'stream' => [
      'ssl' => [
          'allow_self_signed' => true,
          'verify_peer' => false,
          'verify_peer_name' => false,
      ],
    ],
```

at the end of your config/mail.php file. it might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when some changes have been made to files, specifically in the .env file

Clear cache using artisan command

`php artisan cache:clear`

Clear config

`php artisan config:clear`

Restart your server

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Sometimes you also need to clear the browser's cache & cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Update MAIL_HOST variable if you are using Mailtrap for on testing instance

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=************
MAIL_PASSWORD=************
```